# Deserializing a simple array from json to add to combobox C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization

I'm trying to list the following array from a json file into items in my combobox.

```
{
"label_selection" : ["Label A","Label B","Label C","Label D","Label E","Label F"]
}
```

Here is my Class:

```
namespace namespace1 {
    [Serializable]
    public class Labels {
        public string label_selection { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject {
        public List<Labels> label_selection { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here is my function:

```
        private void LoadComboItems() {
            string path = @"labelselection/labels.json";
            var str = File.ReadAllText(path);
            var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(str);
            foreach (var element in x.label_selection) {
                label_combobox.Items.Add(element.ToString());
            }
        }
```

I'm getting an error that says:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException
> HResult=0x80131500
> Message=Error converting value "Label A" to type 'namespace1.Labels'. Path 'label_selection[0]', line 2, position 30.
> Source=Newtonsoft.Json

> Inner Exception 1:
> ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String to namespace1.Labels.

The error occurs at:
var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(str);

Can somebody help me with this error? I'm very new to C#. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot cast `System.String to namespace1.Labels.`

What is element <label_combobox> ?
May be it's not Label.

Try crate new Label, and add to label_combobox.

Maybe like this code.

```
Labels= new Labels(); 
label1.label_selection= element.ToString();
label_combobox.Items.Add(label1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The shown json is an object with a property label_selection that is a collection of strings. `label_selection` property is not a collection of
`Labels` objects.

I think this should work:

```
public class RootObject {
      public List<string> label_selection { get; set; } // Change 1. List of strings
}

(...)

var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(str);
foreach (var element in x.label_selection) 
{
    label_combobox.Items.Add(element); // Change 2. No .ToString()
}
```